# Are there (or could there be) electrically charged particles that move at the speed $c$?

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, speed-of-light, mass

A photon, a neutrino (if it has zero rest mass) move at $c$ but what about charged particles? If the answer is no, is there a fundamental reason or just because of the radiation it emits?

Comment: ISRT the answer is: No, because anything with rest mass requires infinite energy to accelerate to c, and infinite energy isn't available.

Comment: AIUI, in the unbroken SU(2) X U(1) electroweak theory, the charged vector bosons would propagate at $c$.

Comment: Related:  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7905/

Answer (score 2):

It's not impossible in principle to have a charged particle with no mass, but there is no known particle that is both charged and massless.  Consequently, all charged particles are required to travel at some speed less than $c$.  Note, however, that electrons at LHC energies are so excited that they functionally are travelling at $c$, since their energies are in GeV, and their rest mass is half of a MeV. It is in fact common in many particle physics calculations to ignore the electron mass, since doing this introduces errors smaller than the dominant sources of error in the problem.