# Can a mass-less charged particle exist?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, particle-physics, mass, charge

According to known discoveries made till now , we have came across all the charged particles which have the property of mass . So can we assume that there is a correlation between charge and mass and hence can we say that a mass-less can't exist.

Comment: Do you mean electric charge or any charge-like property ?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7905/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @StephenG I am considering any charged particle ??