# Elemental electric charge without rest mass

Tags: mass, charge

Does the non-existence of an elemental electric charge without associated rest mass suggest that atleast a part of the definition of electric charge is dependent on that of mass?
I have read from the following link that it is possible to write a theory of massless electric charges which kind of implies that electric charge & mass have nothing to do with each other in terms of independent existence.

[Massless charged particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7905/massless-charged-particles)

But given the fact that we haven't observed any massless particle with electric charge in ***our reality*** yet, does elemental electric charge have got to do something with the rest mass (in our reality)?

Comment: Doesn't this just duplicate the question you linked to? If not, then I can't tell what the question is.

Comment: My question is more specifically whether elemental electric charge has any dependence on the associated rest mass in our reality. I am not questioning here whether massless electrically charged particles exist or not or if they are possible.

Comment: *My question is more specifically whether elemental electric charge has any dependence on the associated rest mass.* It’s the other way around. The electrostatic self-energy of a point charge renormalizes its rest mass.