# Can a massless object have a charge associated with it?

Tags: particle-physics, mass, speed-of-light, charge

So I've been stuck with this thought for a few days and have not been able to find an answer which can clear this doubt.

**Is it necessary for an object to have certain mass associated with it if it has some electric charge?**

I sure know that in the case of it's converse, **surely an object with some mass may not have a charge associated with it.**

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7905/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I have answered this in the declared duplicate, because that is answering a different, imo, question.