# What would be the implications of finding a massless particle capable of carrying electric charge?

Tags: particle-physics, mass, charge

I came up with this question after discussing with a colleague (we're not physicists) about whether there existed a way of transferring electric charge without transferring mass. My question might be closed for being too open but I just wanted to know if finding a mass-less particle with charge would break our knowledge of our Universe's physics in some way.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7905

Comment: @nihar thanks. Autovoted to close my own question as duplicate instead of deleting it to preserve the way I asked for the same topic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Massless charged particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7905/)